# mootools modalbox with checkbox

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, mootools

I am have implemented a modalbox into my website, the works on a `<a>` like below,

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="moodalbox">External Site</a>
```

Click this link will launch example.com in a modal window.  I am wanting to recreate this effect however instead of using a link I would like to use a checkbox, is this possible? I know that checkboxes do not support `rel` or `href`, so with mootools is there a way to put a listener on the checkbox and launch the modal box to a specified url?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u tried the workaround i suggested, Squeezebox is a modal-box from mootools, what i have suggested you is a way to implment squeezebox. http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/ can suggest you more about squeezebox. If it still it doesnt works tell me i believe i can definetly help u with this

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround can be clicking on a hidden link. On click of checkbox.

Also the method below can help you override modalbox behaviour

```
window.addEvent('domready', {

    /**
     * Set default options, overrideable from later calls.
     */
    SqueezeBox.initialize({
        size: {x: 350, y: 400}
    });

    /**
     * Assign SqueezeBox to all links with rel="boxed" attribute, the class then reads the "href".
     */
    SqueezeBox.assign($$('a[rel=boxed]'));

    /**
     * Open some content manually
     */
    SqueezeBox.open('manual.html'); // handler defaults to "ajax" for urls

    SqueezeBox.open('http://digitarald.de', {handler: 'iframe'}); // we force the "iframe" handler here ...

    SqueezeBox.open($('welcome'), {handler: 'adopt'}); // and here we force "adopt" handler
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand how this answer helps me, what exactly is squeezeBox